# Why is Firefox not showing the whole feed?

Tags: firefox, rss, feed

So, I have this feed. I know it's a full text feed because that's what I selected in WordPress and I checked it in Chrome and confirmed that.

However, Firefox is only showing snippets of my posts. This is strange, because I know I've had Firefox showing full text feeds before, like on Blogger, for example.

Hummm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer over [at Devils Workshop](http://www.devilsworkshop.org/force-firefox-to-display-your-full-feeds-wordpress-hack/).

> RSS 2.0 &  ATOM  have exclusive
>   support for summaries. In RSS 2.0,
>   actual content is placed in content
>   element while summaries can be
>   optionally put in description element.
>   Similarly in ATOM, actual content is
>   placed in content element while
>   summaries can be optionally put in
>   summary element.
>
> Now other browsers displays data from
>   content but Firefox uses data in
>   description (for RSS 2.0) or summary
>   (for Atom). These element are optional
>   so by commenting them we force firefox
>   to use data in content field. As both
>   description & summary are optional
>   element in their formats at item/post
>   levels, feeds are still valid. In
>   fact, blogger.com by default don’t use
>   these elements so this problem does
>   not arise there.
>
> Actually this can be seen as a feature
>   too as you can see entire feed without
>   much scrolling. But firefox should
>   somehow tell a user that full feeds
>   area also available whenever
>   applicable.

Answer (score 3):

FF is "styling" your feed. Since web browsers aren't really meant to consume feeds it just makes things pretty for you.

To see what's really going on, while the feed is loaded in Firefox hit View - Source and you'll see the real deal in all of that XML goodness.

Comment: *checks* Yep, you're right about that. But do you know why it only does it with some feeds? I'm pretty sure it's not in the source code originally, because I searched for a bit of the Firefox source code in Chrome and it's not there.

Comment: I honestly don't know -- does it treat atom and rss differently? Perhaps that's what you've seen?

Comment: Actually, I checked that too. It doesn't appear to be the case. I just hope it's the browsers fault and not mine (or WordPress').